# Dot product of almost perpendicular vectors

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, linear-algebra, numerical-methods, approximation

Suppose $\hat{x}^\top \hat{y} = 1 + \mathcal{O}(\delta^2)$ as $\delta\to0$, where $\hat{x}$ and $\hat{y}$ are **unit vectors**. Can I say that for $\hat{z}\perp \hat{x}$ we then have $\hat{z}^\top \hat{y} = 0 + \mathcal{O}(\delta^2)$?

Comment: No, as you only get $\hat y-\hat x=O(δ)$.

Comment: @LutzLehmann how did you get that?

Comment: Because $\|\hat x-\hat y\|=\|\hat x\|^2-2\hat x^T\hat y+\|\hat y\|^2=2(1-\hat x^T\hat y)=O(δ^2)$. Then take the square root.